# Implementing a generic list that can hold multiple data types in Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, list, model-view-controller, javafx, uml

I need to develop a **list** of libraries that will hold multiple library types. For example, the library can be a library of videos, or a library of photos. I want to follow the MVC design pattern using JavaFX if this is of relevance. Please see the UML diagram below in reference to my question:

*Figure 1*

[image]

So I figured I'd use a generic type  for the list in my Library Model like this:

```
public class LibraryModel<T> {
    private List<T> aList;
}
```

However, this won't work because when I instantiate the list of libraries, I need to specify a type. So in this way, I can only specify either a Photo or a Video library as a list, not both.

I tried to introduce a generic type called "Library" that will be listed in the list (as a superclass) to be extended by the PhotoController/VideoController:

*Figure 2*
[image]

```
public class LibraryModel {
    private List<Library> aList;
}
```

In figure 2, I could create a list of generic libraries. But how will this affect my ability to perform specific photo/video tasks? Let's assume I have the following methods:

Superclass methods:

```
displayAll()
add()
remove()
```

Photo library methods:

```
displaySlideShow()
```

Video library methods:

```
playVideo()
```

By storing the libraries as the superclass, how will I be able to call the specific methods of the other library types? Is this even legal?

Please go easy on me, I'm still learning Java, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to implement the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use abstract class

the Library.

```
abstract class Library {

}
```

then create child classes.

the photo library.

```
class PhotoLibrary extends Library {

     displaySlideShow(){

     }   
}
```

the video library.

```
class VideoLibrary extends Library {

        playVideo() {

        }

}
```

in main class or another you can use them.

```
private List<Library> aList;
aList.add(new PhotoLibrary());
VideoLibrary l2 = new VideoLibrary();
aList.add(l2);
```

then you can call available methods using,

```
Library l = aList(i);
if(l instanceof PhotoLibrary) {
     PhotoLibrary pl = (PhotoLibrary)l;
     pl.displaySlideShow();
}
else if(l instanceof VideoLibrary) {
     VideoLibrary vl = (VideoLibrary)l;
     vl.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: In your code, will I be able to leave the library interface empty? I really only want to operate on the list (add/remove/display). They won't have any overlapping methods other than the list operations. And on top of this, will I be able to call specific methods only available to one library like this: aList.get(2).playVideo() // available only if the object is of type VideoLibrary

Comment: I played with your code, which answered my own question. I am definitely confined to the method of the interface if the type of the list is of the interface. Which begs me to question how I can access other methods which don't belong in the interface.